# Android Binder thread is running after unbind operation

Tags: android, android-service, rpc, aidl, android-service-binding

In my android application, binder thread is in RUNNING state even after unbinding the service connection. And moreover the odd thing i notices is binder thread that is RUNNING state is reused for next service RPC call.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Call the unbindService to complete the client's connection to the service

- Dissipates the service if no client is connected to the service.**

I think that you should to check the connection.